# "The request channel timed out attempting to send after 00:01:00. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout."

Tags: c#, wcf

I am having a console client which is consuming a WCF service using channel factory. I am getting time out error, while the call is not hitting WCF opertaion contract.